# Fixed position child, overflow hidden parent. Hiding bottom only

Tags: html, css

I would like to place a series of fixed elements in the same position on a page, and have them be made visible by their parents scrolling into view.

I have this so far: https://codepen.io/porgeet/pen/ywZgyq

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one {
  background: pink;
  color: green;
}

.two {
  background: aquamarine;
  color: blue;
}

.three {
  background: pink;
  color: red;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent one">
    <div class="child">One</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent two">
    <div class="child">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent three">
    <div class="child">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

The overflowed parent only seems to be effecting divs that come after it, rather than preceding.

I'm aiming for One to show, then Two, then Three.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow:hidden` will do nothing in your case because you made the elements to be fixed<sup>1</sup>. What your are facing is the logical result of the painting order since you didn't specify any `z-index` so the second `position:relative` element will be painted above the first `position:fixed` and so on that's why the second background will hide the first title and so on.

With `position:fixed` you won't be able to achieve this because your code is almost equivalent to the below one where there is no more relation between the parent element and child.

```css
.parent,
.child{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%;
}

.one {
  background: pink;
}
.one + .child {  
color: green;
}

.two {
  background: aquamarine;
}
.two + .child {
  color: blue;
 }

.three {
  background: pink;
}
.three + .child {
  color: red;
}
.child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent one"></div>
<div class="child">One</div>
<div class="parent two"></div>
<div class="child">Two</div>
<div class="parent three"></div>
<div class="child">Three</div>
```

I think your only way to achieve the needed effect is to consider some JS. Here is an easier idea where you can consider `position:absolute` to be able to use `overflow:hidden`:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scroll = window.scrollY || window.scrollTop || document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--t', scroll+"px");
}
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one {
  background: pink;
  color: green;
}

.two {
  background: aquamarine;
  color: blue;
}

.three {
  background: pink;
  color: red;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-top:var(--t,0);
}

.two .child {
  top: calc(50% - 100vh);
}

.three .child {
  top: calc(50% - 200vh);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent one">
  <div class="child">One</div>
</div>
<div class="parent two">
  <div class="child">Two</div>
</div>
<div class="parent three">
  <div class="child">Three</div>
</div>
```

The trick is to adjust margin using the scroll of window to move all the element the same way and initially we position them at the same position in the screen that's why I added `100vh` and `200vh` to move the element upper.

We can also adjust the translate:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scroll = window.scrollY || window.scrollTop || document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--t', scroll+"px");
}
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one {
  background: pink;
  color: green;
}

.two {
  background: aquamarine;
  color: blue;
}

.three {
  background: pink;
  color: red;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(calc(-50% + var(--t,0px)));
}

.two .child {
  top: calc(50% - 100vh);
}

.three .child {
  top: calc(50% - 200vh);
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent one">
  <div class="child">One</div>
</div>
<div class="parent two">
  <div class="child">Two</div>
</div>
<div class="parent three">
  <div class="child">Three</div>
</div>
```

---

> <sup>1</sup>This property specifies whether content of a block container element is clipped when it overflows the element's box. It affects the clipping of all of the element's content **except any descendant elements** (and their respective content and descendants) whose **containing block is the viewport** or an ancestor of the element.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow)</sup>

> Fixed positioning is a subcategory of absolute positioning. The only difference is that for a fixed positioned box, t**he containing block is established by the viewport**.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning)</sup>

Comment: Of course, the painting order. That's what was confusing me, I read that fixed position is relative to the view order but couldn't understand the aforementioned effect.

I see you're pushing the elements further down the more you scroll, keeping them in the same visual position. The -vh is pushing them out of sight initially. Thank you